# IE9 not working for a specific domain user

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, user-profile, internet-explorer-9

User logged on this morning. Could not get IE9 to load any web pages. Logged in under Admin and my non-admin account, works fine browsing web.

There's no extra browser toolbar things like Ask, Google Search, etc enabled or even installed. The only plugins are Adobe Flash, Reader, and Java.  If I run CCleaner, it loads msn.com but the browser itself gets frozen so I can't even open up File, Edit, Tools, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming the user profile on the computer to something else (like `[username].old`), having the user log back in to recreate it, and then open IE.  Should work, and you can copy the user's files and favorites and such back into the new user folder.

Alternately, you can do a lot of troubleshooting to figure out what, precisely, in the user's profile got corrupted and is tanking IE, and fix *that*, but it's a lot faster to have Windows just recreate the user profile.  If it becomes a recurring issue, investigate, but I generally don't think it's a good idea to waste hours of time figuring out why this happened as an isolated event when there's a <60 second fix available.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.

Comment: Just started working. No reboot or logoff either. Odd.

Comment: @Markaway Blame user, hit with keyboard.

Comment: haha I'm about to.